# After packaging my worklight project through ripple it produces only .zip file, no.cod file..?

Tags: blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst, ripple

After packaging my worklight application through ripple for blackberry 7, It generates only .Zip file in the destination folder. There isn't any .cod file which i can deploy to my blackberry device.

Ripple version - 0.9.16 (beta)
Blackberry WebWroks SDK - 2.3.1.5

Target device - Blackberry curve 9370

In the Ripple Services CMD window, there is the following error:

> ... ... ... out: [INFO] out: Compiling BlackBerry WebWorks application
>
> out: [FATAL] out: Executable name has embedded quote, split the
>   arguments
>
> Done build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: the FATAL error that appears in your Ripple Services CMD window seems due to a Java issue; you may need to downgrade it. Please see this topic at the BlackBerry forums: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Executable-name-has-embedded-quote-split-the-arguments/td-p/2330991

---

Have you made sure to start Ripple Services (there is a button for it in the Ripple UI)?
Look at the Ripple Services CMD window after trying to package the project. See if any errors pop up there.

Please also edit your question and describe the steps you have taken to set-up Ripple prior to  packaging.

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/packaging_your_app_in_ripple_1904611_11.html

Comment: how can i send you my log file..plz tell me i need help regarding this as early as possible...

Comment: Settings for ripple services: SDK Path : C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5   Project Root : C:\Users\ujjawal\workspace\Accord_Test_B\apps\Accord_Test_B\blackberry\native   Rchive Name : Mybbapp  Output Folder : C:\Mybbapp

Comment: Have you looked into the ..\Output\StandardInstall folder? There I see a .cod file to use.

Comment: I edited your question - the build is not successfull... do you not see the FATAL message that appears there...?

Comment: See this thread in the blackberry forums about this issue: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Executable-name-has-embedded-quote-split-the-arguments/td-p/2330991

Comment: srry i haven't noticed that .... by the way thanx for your help ...i am using java 7u21 (or 1.7.21) now i am trying this on 1.6 version ... if it works fine i will let you know...thnx again...

Comment: Move the SDK to C:\ and remove any spaces from the path (change the folder names); BlackBerry is not an easy environment to work with... :)